# JSON array and make it show on Android app

Tags: java, android, spring

I have been playing around with trying to get a JSON to an android app which lead me to this.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/

the JSON to this was a simple 1 line file.

```
{"id":1,"content":"Hello, World!"}
```

Followed all instructions to it and it worked fine. Now I want to make it more complicated and pass it s JSON array.Which is like this.

```
[{"eventid":2,"SiteName":"site1","Header":"01/01/2001","Description":null},{"eventid":2,"SiteName":"site1","Header":"Sales","Description":"3072.60"},{"eventid":2,"SiteName":"site1","Header":"Covers","Description":"0"},{"eventid":2,"SiteName":"site1","Header":"Promotions","Description":"24.50"}]
```

followed the instructions and everything and somehow i get this error.

```
03-08 16:02:33.501 11571-11585/com.example.rest E/MainActivity: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of com.example.rest.greeting out of START_ARRAY token
```

Here is my greeting.java code:

```
package com.example.rest;


public class greeting {
private String eventid;
private String SiteName;
private String Header;
private String Description;

public String getEventid() {
    return this.eventid;
}

public String getSiteName() {
    return this.SiteName;
}
public String getHeader() {
    return this.Header;
        }

       public String getDescription() {
            return this.Description;
       }

    }
```

And here is the code that pulls the JSON.

```
private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, greeting> {
@Override
protected greeting doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        final String url = "URL";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        greeting greeting = restTemplate.getForObject(url, greeting.class);
        return greeting;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

how do I go about using Spring on JSON Arrays?

Comment: should `null` be `"null"` in your data

Comment: when i asked for the data, it gave me null and not "null" unfortunately. does it stop it from working?

Comment: json has to start with `{` and end with `}`, which is not the case in your complex example.

Comment: oh does it not show that there is more than one data that is being passed on? or that its an array?